# How to figure out what a .class file does?

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, tomcat, reverse-engineering

I would like to figure out how to reset the age of a battery on a piece of hardware. In the TomCat files I found the function that extracts the age and renders the html:

```
#macro (renderBatteries $batteryList)
#set ($smartBatteryData = $rack.getSmartBatteryData())
#foreach ($battery in $batteryList)
...
<td class="formlabel">Age:</td>
<td width="50%" class="formvalue">$!battery.getBatteryAge() Day(s)
```

So I suppose the interesting function to figure out where it gets information from is `rack.getSmartBatteryData()`?

If I grep for that I see

```
~# grep -R 'getSmartBatteryData' /opt/*
/opt/smu/tomcat/webapps/mgr/templates/app/screens/storage/racks/RackMacros.vm:#set ($smartBatteryData = $rack.getSmartBatteryData())
Binary file /opt/smu/tomcat/webapps/mgr/WEB-INF/lib/SYMsdk.jar matches
Binary file /opt/smu/tomcat/webapps/mgr/WEB-INF/classes/com/bluearc/mgr/data/storageManagement/Rack.class matches
Binary file /opt/smu/tomcat/webapps/mgr/WEB-INF/classes/com/bluearc/mgr/services/storageManagement/LSI/LsiRackViewService.class matches
/opt/smu/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/mgr/templates/app/screens/storage/racks/RackMacros.vm:#set ($smartBatteryData = $rack.getSmartBatteryData())
Binary file /opt/smu/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/mgr/WEB-INF/lib/SYMsdk.jar matches
Binary file /opt/smu/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/mgr/WEB-INF/classes/com/bluearc/mgr/data/storageManagement/Rack.class matches
Binary file /opt/smu/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/mgr/WEB-INF/classes/com/bluearc/mgr/services/storageManagement/LSI/LsiRackViewService.class matches
```

There is a postgres database that I have full access to, and I suppose the battery age is stored somewhere in there.

**Question**

Is is possible to reverse engineer the classes I have found to figure out what `rack.getSmartBatteryData()` does?

Comment: Yes. Use a decompiler and send the .class or the .jar file you want/need to decompile. But note that you probably won't get the real exact code that generated those files, only a very similar representation of it or them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a decompiler like [JD](http://jd.benow.ca/) and send the .class or the .jar file you want/need to decompile. But note that you probably won't get the real exact code that generated those files, only a very similar representation of them.

Comment: `javap` might meet your needs too

Comment: @SteveKuo not really. Check the generated code from `javap -c Foo.class` and let me know if it cann be easily read by humans :)